# enable/disable return key type in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using React Native's TextInput. I noticed that enablesReturnKeyAutomatically makes the keyboard's return key disabled until some text is entered. Is there a way to control the disabled state of the return key myself?

Answer (score -2):

What you could do is implement a custom logic boolean, which you would plug into `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically`. Depending on its state, you could control the setting itself:

```
render = () => {
    let bool = //... some custom logic
    return (
        <TextInput some="values" enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={bool} />
    )
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: this doesn't work as you mentioned. the logic to enable or disable the button is not controlled by the `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` prop. As far as I know you can't control the behaviour

Comment: Note that my answer is from April. I guess the API changed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes :-)

Pass in the `disabled` prop to your "Submit" button.
Create a method on your component, say `isDisabled` that returns either `true` or `false`.
Now in your "Submit Button" pass in `disabled={this.isDisabled()}`.
Its (true or false) value determines whether your return/done/go/next/search/send.. (submit) key is enabled or disabled.

Here is a link from the react native docs: [`disabled` prop on `Button` component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html).
*Note:* the docs do not make it *obvious*, but this prop is also available on `TouchableOpacity`, and related components.

> `disabled`: 
>   If true, disable all interactions for this component.
>   TYPE: `bool`    REQUIRED: No

Here is a pared down MVE Example, directly from one of [my own apps](https://github.com/SherylHohman/ReactND-C4-Project3-UdaciCards-sh):
`canSubmit()` is the name of the function that turns the submit key on/off):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput} from 'react-native';

class NewDeck extends React.Component {

  state = {
    title: '',
    beenTouched: false,
    errorMessage: '',
  }

  controlledTextInput(prevTitle){
    const isEmptyStringErrorMessage = this.isEmptyStringErrorMessage(title);

    this.setState({
      title,
      errorMessage,
      beenTouched: true,
    });
  }

  isEmptyStringErrorMessage(text){
    return (text.trim() === '')
            ? 'Cannot be an empty string.'
            : ''
  }

  canSubmit(){
    return (!this.state.errorMessage && this.state.beenTouched) &&
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

          <TextInput 
              placeholder='Quiz Deck Title'
              value={this.state.title}
              returnKeyType={ "done" }
          />

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={ () => this.onSubmit()}
            disabled={!this.canSubmit()}
            >
            <Text>
              Submit
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have not tried passing this same property directly into a `TextInput` component itself, but that *might* also work to disable it directly.